# Problems getting a working installation of gsl 2.6

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I need to run some physics software on my laptop, which is very finicky, so I specifically need to use gsl 2.6 (where I normally run I have found this through trial and error).

I run ubuntu-18.04. I had gsl 2.4 installed but could not get it to update further than that. So I went to the gnu website and downloaded 2.7 in the hopes that it would do. I followed the instructions here: https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/11/hello/ to install it. Including creating the little example.c test file, which seemed to work just fine. But when I tried to check the version with `gsl-config --version` it returned 2.4 still.

So I uninstalled gsl and purged it from the system in case the problem was just that I hadn't gotten rid of the other version first (I'm used to unloading and loading gsl as a module normally so I didn't think to remove it first). I tried again with the exact same results except that my laptop now complains that there is no gsl in /usr/bin. I don't know why it is specifically looking there, the old version wasn't installed there, and the new one isn't installed there either.

Can I not just do something like `apt-get install libgsl-dev-2.6` ? Not that specifically - I know that doesn't work! I'm also fine to install manually again if anyone knows what I missed.

Thanks!

---

Edited to add errors after attempting N0rbert's solution *

```
libtool: install: ranlib /home/cb27g11/Downloads/gsl-2.6+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.a
libtool: warning: remember to run 'libtool --finish /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/cb27g11/Downloads/gsl-2.6+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/bin'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c gsl-randist gsl-histogram '/home/cb27g11/Downloads/gsl-2.6+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/bin'
libtool: warning: 'libgsl.la' has not been installed in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
libtool: warning: '/home/cb27g11/Downloads/gsl-2.6+dfsg/cblas/libgslcblas.la' has not been installed in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
libtool: warning: 'cblas/libgslcblas.la' has not been installed in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/gsl-randist /home/cb27g11/Downloads/gsl-2.6+dfsg/debian/tmp/usr/bin/gsl-randist
libtool: warning: 'libgsl.la' has not been installed in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
libtool: warning: '/home/cb27g11/Downloads/gsl-2.6+dfsg/cblas/libgslcblas.la' has not been installed in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
libtool: warning: 'cblas/libgslcblas.la' has not been installed in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
```

Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: GSL 2.4 is available is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gsl&searchon=sourcenames). There is a PPA with [2.5 version](https://launchpad.net/~savoury1/+archive/ubuntu/inkscape/+packages?field.name_filter=gsl&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=bionic). Please add some details to your question. Currently it is puzzle, so not reproducible.

Comment: If you want `/usr/bin/gsl-config` , the "gsl-2.7/" source must be configured with `./configure --prefix=/usr`

Comment: ... to trash the system. Use --prefix=/usr/local to keep it manageable.

Comment: To run newer software, you will have best results if you run a newer release of Ubuntu. For GSL 2.6, specifically Ubuntu 21.04 or pre-release 21.10 have 2.6 in their repositories.  If you don't want to migrate away from 18.10, it's possible to run 21.04 in a WM or container.

Comment: @N0rbert. »»... to trash the system«« : `libgsl23` / `libgsl[any-version]` is not a system package. GSL / libgsl is not installed by default.

Comment: Ok, so install stuff to /usr/bin makes system manageable. Very smart. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build GSL 2.6 on 18.04 LTS from [sources](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hirsute/gsl) by using commands below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev debhelper

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsl/gsl_2.6+dfsg.orig.tar.gz
tar -xf gsl_2.6+dfsg.orig.tar.gz
cd gsl-2.6+dfsg/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsl/gsl_2.6+dfsg-2.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf gsl_2.6+dfsg-2.debian.tar.xz
rm gsl_2.6+dfsg-2.debian.tar.xz

dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
sudo apt-get install ../*gsl*.deb
```

to get

> ```
> $ gsl-config --version
> 2.6
> ```

and then try to compile your application.

Comment: Thankyou for your thorough answer!

Unfortunately I seem to have run into some problems at the "dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us" step:

I will add full details of the errors in my original post but at the end I get this:

dpkg-genchanges: warning: package libgsl-prof in control file but not in files list
dpkg-genchanges: info: not including original source code in upload
 dpkg-source --after-build gsl-2.6+dfsg
dpkg-source: info: unapplying manual-page-correction
dpkg-source: info: unapplying gsl-cblas-linkage
dpkg-buildpackage: info: binary and diff upload (original source NOT included)

Comment: I thinks  that those are just warnings, you can proceed with `sudo apt-get install ../*gsl*.deb` to have deb-packages installed.

Comment: You appear to be right, after proceeding with the install step gsl-config --version returns 2.6 ! Thank-you very much!